# Making unique list in python

Tags: python

What is the most pythonic way of making a list unique using custom equality operator?

For instance you have a list of dicts `L`, and you want a new list `M` such that for all dicts `d`, `e` in `M` and one specific `x`

```
d[x] != e[x]
```

How can this be done?

Comment: Now *that* is a highly localized question.

Answer (score 3):

In your case (and all cases where equivalence boils down to the equivalence of some kind of key), you can simply construct a dictionary, where the keys are the values you want to compare:

```
L = [{'key': 'foo', 'v': 42}, {'key': 'bar', 'v': 43}, {'key': 'foo', 'v': 44}]
x = 'key'
M = {d[x]:d for d in L}.values()
# In old Python versions: dict((d[x],d for d in L)).values()
```

Note that the result is not deterministic, both

```
[{'key': 'foo', 'v': 44}, {'key': 'bar', 'v': 43}]
```

and

```
[{'key': 'foo', 'v': 42}, {'key': 'bar', 'v': 43}]
```

are valid results.

In the general case, simply check all accepted values:

```
def unique(iterable, is_eq):
  tmp = []
  for el in iterable:
    if not any(is_eq(inTmp, el) for inTmp in tmp):
      tmp.append(is_eq)
  return tmp
```

Note that this means that your comparison function will be called `O(n²)` times instead of `n` times.

Comment: this is very nice for the specific example..but i was expecting a more generalized solution in lines of unique(lst, key=MyFunc) like in sorting.

Comment: @FUD added a generalized version

Answer (score 1):

Based on FUD's comment to phihag. Note that `key` function must return a hashable value.

```
def unique(iterable, key=lambda x : x):
    seen = set()
    res = []
    for item in iterable:
        k = key(item)
        if k not in seen:
            res.append(item)
            seen.add(k)
    return res

from operator import itemgetter
L = [{'key': 'foo', 'v': 42}, {'key': 'bar', 'v': 43}, {'key': 'foo', 'v': 44}]
print unique(L, key=itemgetter('key'))
#[{'key': 'foo', 'v': 42}, {'key': 'bar', 'v': 43}]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this sort of thing admits a one-liner, but it seems to me that the `set` class is the key to what you want.

```
M = []
uniques = set(d[x] for d in L)
for d in L:
    if d[x] in uniques:
        uniques.remove(d[x])
        M.append(d)
```

Note: phihag's answer seems more Pythonic, but this might be a bit more self-documenting

Answer (score 0):

Using dictionary comprehension:

```
def unique(itrable,key):
    return {key(x):x for x in itrable}.values()

>>> unique('abcdbbcdab', lambda x: x)
['a', 'c', 'b', 'd']

>>> unique([10, -20, 20, 30], lambda x: abs(x))
[10, 20, 30]
```